# Providing unique directives to proxy block by virtual host

Tags: apache, configuration, reverse-proxy

Say I have the following `Proxy` block in my main config:

```
<Proxy balancer://PrivateSSL/>
  BalanceMember http://host:8080/ route=01 loadfactor=100
  BalanceMember http://host:8080/ roout=02 loadfactor=100
  ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
```

Now, in a `VirtualHost` can I "enhance/spice/modify" that block like so:

```
<VirtualHost ip:port>
   ...
   <Proxy balancer://PrivateSSL/>
     RequestHeader set Host reverse-proxy-host
   </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

without having all the previously defined `Proxy` elements repeated?

I'm actually going to play with this, but the community might have a pattern that works better (maybe saying that is *verboten*, but I think others will benefit from the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing locally is going to be a dog. But [some RTFM helped out](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#mergin):

> The configuration sections are applied in a very particular order. Since this can have important effects on how configuration directives are interpreted, it is important to understand how this works.
>
> The order of merging is:
>
> 1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and .htaccess done
>      simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
> 2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory ~>`)
> 3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done
>      simultaneously
> 4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
> 5. `<If>`
>
> ...
>
> When the request is served by mod_proxy, *the `<Proxy>` container takes the place of the `<Directory>` container in the processing order*.

Comment: I was able to test in a development environment. The above hypothesis of adding directives to a common proxy configuration in virtual host containers was proven correct.